# Complete list of date ranges to full year

Tags: r, date

I have the following example data frame:

```
Date_from <- c("2013-01-01","2013-05-10","2013-08-13","2013-11-19")
Date_to <- c("2013-05-07","2013-08-12","2013-11-18","2013-12-25")
y <- data.frame(Date_from,Date_to)
y$concentration <- c("1.5","2.5","1.5","3.5")
y$Date_from <- as.Date(y$Date_from)
y$Date_to <- as.Date(y$Date_to)
y$concentration <- as.numeric(y$concentration)
```

I use the following code to detect gaps in date ranges and add the missing date ranges into the data frame and asign NA to the missing concentration:

```
adding<-data.frame(Date_from=y$Date_to[-nrow(y)]+1,Date_to=y$Date_from[-1]-1,concentration=NA)
adding<-adding[ adding$Date_from<adding$Date_to,]
res<-rbind(y,adding)
res[order(res$Date_from),]
```

This results in:

```
Date_from    Date_to concentration
2013-01-01 2013-05-07           1.5
2013-05-08 2013-05-09            NA
2013-05-10 2013-08-12           2.5
2013-08-13 2013-11-18           1.5
2013-11-19 2013-12-25           3.5
```

The problem now is that the data frame ends at 2013-12-25 and not 2013-12-31. How can I do the following:

1. Detect the ending date of the last date range in the data frame, e.g. 2013-12-25
2. Add one additional line and calculate new date range up to the last day of the year and add NA for concentration

The results should look like this:

```
Date_from    Date_to concentration
2013-01-01 2013-05-07           1.5
2013-05-08 2013-05-09            NA
2013-05-10 2013-08-12           2.5
2013-08-13 2013-11-18           1.5
2013-11-19 2013-12-25           3.5
2013-12-26 2013-12-31            NA
```

Comment: Wasn't this posted yesterday?

Comment: I was thinking about adding it to my question from yesterday but thought it might be of interest as a separate topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you just want this?

```
df <- read.table(text = "
Date_from    Date_to concentration
2013-01-01 2013-05-07           1.5
2013-05-08 2013-05-09            NA
2013-05-10 2013-08-12           2.5
2013-08-13 2013-11-18           1.5
2013-11-19 2013-12-25           3.5", h = T, stringsAsFactors = F)


rbind(df, c(as.character(max(as.Date(df$Date_to))+1), paste0(substr(max(as.Date(df$Date_to)), 1, 4),"-12-31")  , NA))


   Date_from    Date_to concentration
1 2013-01-01 2013-05-07           1.5
2 2013-05-08 2013-05-09          <NA>
3 2013-05-10 2013-08-12           2.5
4 2013-08-13 2013-11-18           1.5
5 2013-11-19 2013-12-25           3.5
6 2013-12-26 2013-12-31          <NA>
```

Comment: I need to be able to detect the date automatically (and the year). The year 2013 was just an example so just writing the last day of the year 2013 wouldn´t help.

Comment: Does it have to be a character? I will need the concentration in numeric. However, when using 
    rbind(df, c(as.numeric(as.character(max(as.Date(df$Date_to))+1), paste0(substr(max(as.Date(df$Date_to)), 1, 4),"-12-31")  , NA)))
it doesn´t work properly.

Comment: with that code you are trying to make make 3 columns numeric, why would you try that? Without the `as.numeric()` the `concentration` column is already numeric...  what you were trying was this: `as.numeric("2013-12-26", "2013-12-31", NA)`, that really won't work

Comment: when I run it `str()` shows `$ concentration: chr  "1.5" NA "2.5" "1.5" ...`

Comment: because you did not assign it to your new dataframe. just add `df <- ` before the `rbind()` function. And without running my code, what does `class(df$concentration)` give? I think it is currently character in your df, so just do `df$concentration <- as.numeric(df$concentration)` at the end

Answer (score 1):

You can use this explicit function

```
date_order<-function(dt){
  for(i in 1:(nrow(dt)-1)){
    if(dt[[1]][i+1] - dt[[2]][i] > 1){
      pre<-dt[[2]][i] + 1
      post<-dt[[1]][(i+1)] - 1
      add<-data.frame("Date_from" = pre,"Date_to" = post,"concentration" = NA)
      dt2<-rbind.data.frame(dt,add)
    }
  }
  if(exists("dt2") == F){
    dt2<-dt
  }
  dt2<-dt2[order(dt2$Date_from),]
  yr<-substr(x = dt[[2]][nrow(dt)],start = 1,stop = 4)
  last_day<-as.Date(paste(yr,"12-31",sep = "-"),format = "%Y-%m-%d")
  if(dt[[2]][nrow(dt)] != last_day){
    add2<-data.frame("Date_from" = dt[[2]][nrow(dt)] + 1,"Date_to" = last_day,"concentration" = NA)
    dt2<-rbind.data.frame(dt2,add2)
  }
  return(dt2)
}
```

Using this function with your data returns this:

```
> date_order(y)
    Date_from    Date_to concentration
1  2013-01-01 2013-05-07           1.5
5  2013-05-08 2013-05-09            NA
2  2013-05-10 2013-08-12           2.5
3  2013-08-13 2013-11-18           1.5
4  2013-11-19 2013-12-25           3.5
11 2013-12-26 2013-12-31            NA
```

Hope that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to join `y` with a dataframe that contains all possible periods (either explicitely given or the "remainder") within the year. The solution below is using `data.table` syntax and the `floor_date()` and `ceiling_date()` functions from the `lubridate` package. This ensures that the solution will work even if the given periods span multiple years.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
# coerce character dates to numeric dates
cols <- c("Date_from", "Date_to")
setDT(y, key = cols)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.IDate), .SDcols = cols]
# create sequence of starting points of all periods
breaks <- y[, c(Date_from, Date_to + 1L)] %>% 
  # append start and end of year
  c(lubridate::floor_date(min(.), "year"), 
           lubridate:: ceiling_date(max(.), "year")) %>% 
  sort() %>% 
  unique() %T>%
  print()
```

> ```
> [1] "2013-01-01" "2013-05-08" "2013-05-10" "2013-08-13" "2013-11-19" "2013-12-26" "2014-01-01"
> ```

```
# create periods
x <- data.table(from = head(breaks, -1L), to = tail(breaks, -1L) - 1L, 
                key = c("from", "to"))
x
```

> ```
>          from         to
> 1: 2013-01-01 2013-05-07
> 2: 2013-05-08 2013-05-09
> 3: 2013-05-10 2013-08-12
> 4: 2013-08-13 2013-11-18
> 5: 2013-11-19 2013-12-25
> 6: 2013-12-26 2013-12-31
> ```

```
# right join to create the expected result
y[x]
```

> ```
>     Date_from    Date_to concentration
> 1: 2013-01-01 2013-05-07           1.5
> 2: 2013-05-08 2013-05-09            NA
> 3: 2013-05-10 2013-08-12           2.5
> 4: 2013-08-13 2013-11-18           1.5
> 5: 2013-11-19 2013-12-25           3.5
> 6: 2013-12-26 2013-12-31            NA
> ```